# Software that will receive all your promotional email and send you a single digest

Tags: email, time-management

I receive too many promotional emails in my GMail account. I want to read it, but I don't want to receive a new email every 20 minutes...

I know there is software out there that receives all this promotional stuff for you, and then, at the end of the day/ week, sends you a single email with all that "happened" in your inbox...

I'm looking for programs that do this. Can someone recommend one?

Comment: This would be hard because how would the software know what is promotional and what is not? Maybe a spam checker that would send you an email containing all spam?

Comment: @Tom, after this post, I did find a few: [Unroll.me](https://unroll.me) and [ADigest](http://devpost.com/software/adigest)... Anyone recommends one of these?

Comment: Unroll.me looks interesting, too bad it only works on IOS :/